# Create 200 dirs & copy main.cpp to all of them in batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, directory

Hello i want to do 200 directories and copy to it file "main.cpp", i tryed this, but this don't working and consumes lot of time, my code:

```
@echo off

mkdir 17
copy main.cpp 17/main.cpp

mkdir 18
copy main.cpp 18/main.cpp
```

Comment: What a great and detailed error description...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Command Prompt, `[cmd]`:

```bat
For /L %A In (1,1,200) Do @XCopy main.cpp %A\ >Nul
```

From a batch file, `[batch-file]`:

```bat
@For /L %%A In (1,1,200) Do @XCopy main.cpp %%A\ >Nul
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a better sorting with equal length folder numbers,
padded with leading zeros use this batch:

```
@Echo off & Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
For /l %%A in (1001,1,1200) Do (
  Set "Folder=%%A"
  XCopy main.cpp !Folder:~-3!\ >Nul
)
```

Comment: Agreed, _I would have offered a similar answer, but since the OP code clearly didn't provide leading zeroes, I felt it an unnecessary addition to my response_.

Comment: @Compo Just presenting an alternative to your otherwise good solution +1.